# Check if java string has combining characters

Tags: java, string, text, unicode

How to check if a java string contains combining characters?

The wikipedia page specified some characters, but I believe it's not all of them, also I checked unicode v9.0 data table, don't know how characters are marked.

[wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)

[unicode9 data db](http://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData-9.0.0d6.txt)

---

Sample:

```
String a="Java is evil";//does not contain any combining char
String b=" ̤U";// ̤  + U( the  ̤  is combining) 
//or ផ្លូ which means ផ្ + លូ , or គ្នា is គ្ + នា
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you mean?

Comment: Suppose the strings are `"U\u0324"` and `"\u1E72"`. They are different representations of the same thing. Do you want to detect that both have combining characters, or only the first?

Comment: Actually the problem is much complex than this, worst thing would be combining a character from set A with another set. So the target text rendering might be different. for your case  char `01e72` is not complex/combined, but `0324` coming with anything is. @erickson

Comment: Okay, then it sounds like [nj_'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35855491/3474) is what you are looking for. If so, accept it. I was asking, because I thought you might need to perform a decomposition (with `java.text.Normalizer`)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use [regular expressions to match combining marks](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), e.g.

```
String a = "Java is evil";
String b = "U\u0324";
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\p{M}");
System.out.println(p.matcher(a).find());
System.out.println(p.matcher(b).find());
```

Outputs:

```
false
true
```

Comment: very awesome solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Canonical_Combining_Class

> (3) The classes used for the Canonical Ordering Algorithm in the
>   Unicode Standard.

The (3) indicates the third field after the code point value in the unicode data table. If it's non-zero, it's some sort of combining character, per the table at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Canonical_Combining_Class_Values.

Good luck, there's a lot of them :)

Comment: thanks, wonderful,  found it, http://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/extracted/DerivedCombiningClass-9.0.0d17.txt, but I was looking for alternative ways using any api if it's possible. maybe it's better to filter out languages.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create your own map of these characters combining together. I suggest you the multiple usage of `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`.

A very simple way is put these combinations separately to a text file with the following pattern:

```
ý ´ y
ä ¨ a
...
```

Then read the file and save to your multiple maps.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

// Looping, reading all lines
    String line; // A line from the file
    String part[] = line.split(" "); // Separate line with a space delimiter
    Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    tempMap.put(part[1], part[2]);
    map.put(part[0], tempMap);
```

Comment: how may I know if there is a character from ABC language with xyz code is combining!? you have the list!?